# Inno Setup; creating a desktop icon to overide current icon

Tags: icons, inno-setup

I've been playing around with Inno Setup for a couple days now, and have a lot of the kinks worked out except for one I seem to be having an issue with. Its about creating desktop links and icons.

I've tried using the example scripts and putting them into my own script, and I've tried using two separate Setup Wizards (one that came with Inno Setup, and one that I downloaded from InnoIDE). After doing a bit of searching I finally found a code that will get a Desktop item to form (for a while the installer was not creating a desktop icon), but my issue is that the icon remains Adobe instead of my company icon.

In the old installer we used (InstalShield) back before I worked here, the programmer managed to configure the installer so that when the end user Downloaded it a link on the desktop would appear with the company logo, that would launch the main PDF file when clicked. All the files we are using are PDF files. I specified an icon in the installer, but I think thats just for the installer itself (while its running). I couldnt find an option for using a specific icon on the desktop in the Manual, or in the Setup Wizard, and I tried searching Google and couldnt find anyone else with this problem.

Is there a way to make my company logo show up on the desktop instead of Adobe's PDF logo for the main launch file? Or even if there is a way to create a shortcut and have that be the logo and link to the main PDF file, that would be fine too. Any advice really is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a parameter called `IconFilename` which should solve your problem. Example:

```
[Icons]
Name: {group}\MyApplication; Filename: {app}\MyApplication.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconFilename: {app}\MyApplication.ico; Comment: "MyApplication"; Components: MyApplication; 
Name: {commondesktop}\MyApplication; Filename: {app}\MyApplication.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconFilename: {app}\MyApplication.ico; Comment: "MyApplication"; Components: MyApplication;
```

You are free to use an `exe`, a `dll` or an `ico` file to get your company logo icon from using `IconFilename` property.

For more detailed information, visit the link below:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection

Comment: I gave it a shot, copied it in and edited for my file names and .ico file, but when I tried to compile I recieved this error:[ISPP] Undeclared identifier: "InstallPath".

Comment: Use {app} instead if you install into {app}

Comment: you can also define InstallPath like `#define InstallPath "{pf}\MyPublisher\MyApplicationName"` at the beginning of your script. I assumed you had the basic knowledge on InnoSetup, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have metnioned that I'm a beginner with Inno. I've never programmed anything before, and its for my job so I have limited learn time. But I changed it to app, but then got this Mesage:   Error: Directive or parameter "Components" expression error: Parameter "Components" includes an unknown component. I left it saying 'MyApplication' which I think is whats wrong now. I tried to substitute it with one of my define fields, like MyAppExe, but I still get the error. I'm not sure if the file name goes there or the main executable file.

Comment: All parameters are not required. You can simply remove "Components: MyApplication;" part and it should work. Components help you to install more than one component in the same setup package. for example you have a server and a client application. You define both projects under [Components] section and adding "Components: ...;" lines show which icon belongs to which component. This way, if user selects only one component to install, only this component's shortcut is created. This applies to other sections like [Dirs], [Files], [Run] etc.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and deleted Components at the end, and changed 'Comment: "MyApplication"] to 'Comment: "{#MyAppName}" It compiled fine with those changes, and does almost exactly what I want it to. The only problem is that it now creates 2 Desktop Icons. One is how I wanted it, and the other is the PDF. Both shortcuts work. I have a [Task] section too that creates a desktop icon and is listed as 'additional icons', but if I delete [Tasks] and try compiling, it aborts and says 'Perameter "Tasks" includes unknown task in one line of code under [Icons]. It reads Tasks: "desktopicon";

Comment: Ah! I feel bad not waiting for your feedback this time, but I realized I had a duplicate line of code above the line you gave me that the Wizard generated. Figured I didnt need it anymore, since that was the line of code the error was in. Deleted that, deleted the [Task] section I had and it works! Exactly how I wanted it to, thank you so much for your help!